# Open windows search indices and run search on them

Tags: c#, .net, windows, search, windows-runtime

I was just wondering if it is possible to open the indices created by Windows Search and run queries on them. There is a lot of resources spent on creating them so I thought it might be more efficient to just use the existing indices and avoid recreating them.

Ideally, I'd like to use them in my Windows Store app but if there's a limitation in this area but it's possible in general (I'm using C# and .Net), I'd like to know. Thanks.